# Mapping over a heterogenous data structure with a generic function

Tags: haskell, hlist

I'm working on an HList implementation and I'm stuck trying to implement a `map` function for it. I've tried a lot of different approaches but with each one I reach compiler errors related to that function.

Following is an example of how I want to use a generic function `Just` to apply it to all elements of the input data structure.

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

-- | An input heterogenous data structure
recursivePairs :: (Int, (Char, (Bool, ())))
recursivePairs = (1, ('a', (True, ())))

-- | This is how I want to use it
recursivePairs' :: (Maybe Int, (Maybe Char, (Maybe Bool, ())))
recursivePairs' = hMap Just recursivePairs

class HMap f input output where
  hMap :: f -> input -> output

-- | A counterpart of a Nil pattern match for a list
instance HMap f () () where
  hMap _ _ = ()

-- | A counterpart of a Cons pattern match for a list
instance 
  ( HMap f iTail oTail, 
    Apply f iHead oHead ) =>
  HMap f (iHead, iTail) (oHead, oTail) 
  where
    hMap f (head, tail) = (apply f head, hMap f tail)

class Apply f input output where
  apply :: f -> input -> output

instance Apply (input -> output) input output where
  apply = id
```

With this I'm getting the following compiler error:

```
No instance for (Apply (a0 -> Maybe a0) Int (Maybe Int))
  arising from a use of `hMap'
The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
```

Is there at all a way to solve this and if not then why?

Comment: I think the problem is that the type system doesn't realize that you are instantiating `Just` with different concrete types on each successive application because your definition of `hMap` keeps reusing the same `f`.  The first time you apply it the type is `Int -> Maybe Int`, the second time you apply it the type is `Char -> Maybe Char`.  However, I'm still not quite sure how to fix it.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez
Yes, that's exactly the problem. And if you add a fundep `| input output -> f` to the `Apply` class, the error messages will say that it is looking for instances, like `(Bool -> Maybe Bool) Char (Maybe Char)`. I was thinking about using [`cast`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Typeable.html#v:cast) to disconnect the two usages of `f` on a type-level, but that just didn't feel very natural, and depending on `Typeable` wasn't very alluring either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to use a polymorphic function with different arguments, but your `Apply` instance takes a function (a mono-type).  You can easily fix this multiple ways

```
data JustIfy = JustIfy
instance Apply JustIfy a (Maybe a) where
  apply _ = Just

recursivePairs' :: (Maybe Int, (Maybe Char, (Maybe Bool, ())))
recursivePairs' = hMap JustIfy recursivePairs
```

works with your code just fine

EDIT: A more general approach to the same thing is (requiring `RankNTypes`)

```
--A "universal" action that works on all types
newtype Univ f = Univ (forall x. x -> f x)
instance Apply (Univ f) x (f x) where
   apply (Univ f) x = f x

recursivePairs' :: (Maybe Int, (Maybe Char, (Maybe Bool, ())))
recursivePairs' = hMap (Univ Just) recursivePairs
```

or if you are using a recent ish version of GHC and are willing to turn on more extensions

```
newtype Univ' c f = Univ' (forall x. c x => x -> f x)
instance c x => Apply (Univ' c f) x (f x) where
  apply (Univ' f) x = f x

class All x
instance All x

recursivePairs' :: (Maybe Int, (Maybe Char, (Maybe Bool, ())))
recursivePairs' = hMap (Univ' Just :: Univ' All Maybe) recursivePairs
```

which is nice since then it lets you do things like include a "show" in the function you map with.

For a more general solution, check out [Oleg's Type level lambda caclulus](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/TypeLambdaVal.hs) which allows you to write code at the value level and then auto-magically infers the appropriate type level program.  Unfortunetly, Oleg's solution is at this point rather old, and uses a nominal implementation of the LC which I don't particularly like.  I've been thinking about how to do better, but might hold off until deciable equality comes to type families.

My view is that HLists should these days be done using GADTs and DataKinds rather than tuples.  Type families are preferable to functional dependencies, but currently are more limited because they lack decidable equality.

Comment: Thank you. You say there are multiple ways to solve this - could you please elaborate more on this? I'm looking for an optimal solution, so there's no requirement to stick to the provided code in any way, it is just an abstract example. Is there a way to solve this without having to declare specific instances for each function I want to use with `hMap`?

Comment: @NikitaVolkov I have added more general solutions

Answer (score 1):

Although the following does not exactly answer the question (so I won't be accepting it), it does solve the problem concerning mapping the structure without requiring any additional instances for applicative functors:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

import Control.Applicative

main = do
  print $ (hPure recursivePairs :: (Maybe Int, (Maybe Char, (Maybe Bool, ()))))
  print $ (hPure recursivePairs :: ([Int], ([Char], ([Bool], ()))))

recursivePairs :: (Int, (Char, (Bool, ())))
recursivePairs = (1, ('a', (True, ())))

class HPure input output where
  hPure :: input -> output

instance HPure () () where
  hPure _ = ()

instance  
  ( Applicative f, 
    HPure iTail oTail ) => 
  HPure (iHead, iTail) (f iHead, oTail) 
  where hPure (iHead, iTail) = (pure iHead, hPure iTail)
```

Outputs:

```
(Just 1,(Just 'a',(Just True,())))
([1],("a",([True],())))
```